# Position a div after another

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a `div` after another vertically, and some div's to the right and other to the left, like text messages.

I have something like this but it's not doing the trick.

Any ideas?

```css
container {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='right'>
    "text to the right"
  </div>
  <div class='left'>
    "text to the left"
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    "text to the right"
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your CSS selectors are all missing periods. E.g. `.container`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix the typo mentioned by @j08691 and add `clear: both` to `.right` and `.left`.

See the snippet below:

```css
container {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.right {
  clear: both;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.left {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='right'>
    "text to the right"
  </div>
  <div class='left'>
    "text to the left"
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    "text to the right"
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Save the trouble by using Flexbox model for the parent container and `text-align` property for the child elements.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* Align them vertically */
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='right'>
    "text to the right"
  </div>
  <div class='left'>
    "text to the left"
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    "text to the right"
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also use `align-self: flex-end` for the `.right`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.right {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='right'>
    "text to the right"
  </div>
  <div class='left'>
    "text to the left"
  </div>
  <div class='right'>
    "text to the right"
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do it:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
}

.right {
  margin-left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Hope it helps